# Cloud Functions Firestore Sending push notification to a specific user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have chat app I am using Firebase firestore DB, I am saving the recent messages like follows

Sender Side:
Messages -> currentUserId -> recent_messages

Receiver Side:
Messages -> recieverId -> recent_messages

That means the same message will be written to both current user and the the receiver user documents. (same message will be written to two different documents)

the message content is like follows:

**- sender side**

```swift
 let fromData = ["text": text , "uid": toId, "userProfileUrl":  userAvatarUrl, "timestamp": Timestamp(date: Date()), "seen": false]
```

**-receiver side**

```swift
 let toData = ["text": text  ,"uid": currentUserID, "userProfileUrl":  currentUser?.profileImageUrl ?? "", "timestamp": Timestamp(date: Date()),"seen": false]
```

Now I want to observe the `recent_messages` collection and only send a notification to the receiver user Is there any way **to avoid** send push notification to both of them?

Comment: Hello, can you add to your question the code of your Cloud Function?

Answer (score 2):

Get the registration token of the reciever user:

```
// Callback fired if Instance ID token is updated.
messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
  messaging.getToken().then((refreshedToken) => {
    console.log('Token refreshed.');
    // Indicate that the new Instance ID token has not yet been sent to the
    // app server.
    setTokenSentToServer(false);
    // Send Instance ID token to app server.
    sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
    // ...
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
    showToken('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
  });
});
```

Then use `sendToDevice` to send the notification to the user:

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
  .then(function(response) {

    console.log('Successfully sent:', response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error sending:', error);
  });
```

You can send the token to the server by adding it to the database, then in the server side you can read from the database and retrieve the token.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging.html#send-todevice